# Сколько сейчас стоит разработка собственного почтового сервера?

Tags: smtp, email, интерфейс, pop3

Знакомый спрашивает. Хочет свой сервер по типу Gmail, только интерфейс попроще и функции попроще (отправка писем и т.д.).

Есть вопросы:

1. Какие бесплатные и желательно Open Source, решения можно использовать для реализации его просьбы? (Подразумеваю готовые веб-морды, готовые сервера под линукс желательно)
2. Какую сумму назвать? Я могу, в принципе, ему с нуля все написать, но даже не знаю, сколько брать, объем работы большой, как по мне.

Умею в SQL, PHP, C#, Java. Опыт есть. Думаю, за месяц с нуля напишу первую бажную версию. Ваши советы.

Comment: [20 млн](http://bash.im/quote/405106)

Comment: В какой валюте?

Comment: Я тоже хочу распиливать гос бюджет :/ Где встать в очередь и кто последний?

Comment: Я уж испугался, подумал вы серьезно.

Comment: вот он наш ответ на outlook.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объём работы действительно большой. И вряд-ли ради разового заказа стоит писать новый почтовик :-) Возьмите что-то готовое.

Веб морды:

- [Roundcube](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoundCube_Webmail) - он практически совершенен. Нет других OpenSource веб-почтовиков со сравнимым качеством и функционалом.
- [Белка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquirrelMail) - простая и надёжная. Интерфейс там действительно попроще :-)

Готовые сервера под линукс:

[Тут список](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_email_server_software) есть. Выбирайте тот, по которому больше документации по настройке.

Comment: последняя ссылка не туда

Comment: с двоетичиями в урле у парсера явно проблемы

Comment: @Spectre ага, напрочь.

Comment: И сколько по вашему стоит работа, включающая в себя настройку готовых решений без лишних заморочек и без расхода на сервера и т.д.?